# confusing the php version show in terminal and phpinfo

Tags: php

I'm confusing with my PHP version showing in my terminal and phpinfo info. as you can see in the image attached below.. [image: diffrent between phpinfo and terminal info]

anybody can help me fix this. Im trying to learn cakephp and the missing part is only the extension intl.

Comment: The CLI can have a totally different version installed versus the webserver's version. Entirely normal. I tend to replace the default OSX install of PHP/Apache with my own via Homebrew.

Comment: can you share how u update it @ceejayoz

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: im using mac. high sierra

Comment: Take a look at this [article](https://jason.pureconcepts.net/2016/09/upgrade-php-mac-os-x/). I used it to uniformize my mac's php version with the one installed by [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/).

Comment: i install xampp and stop apache -sudo apachectl stop- then run the xampp server.. when i type which php, its still return /usr/local/bin/php

Answer (score 1):

You either upgraded php and did not restart the web service (FPM or Apache) or you have two versions installed, and they are not slotted correctly.  For a more complete answer, please provide more information about your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and enter

> which php

Change to your correct php dir in

> ~/.bash_profile

Comment: nothing change sir.. i change this part /usr/local/bin/php in /.bash_profile

Comment: what is your 'which php' output? and what webserver do you use?

Comment: which php return this /usr/local/bin/php and im using apache (run local).. its still give the 7.1.7 version and php.ini show in php info also wrong.. u can see in the pic above..

Comment: i install xampp and stop apache -sudo apachectl stop- then run the xampp server.. check the phpinfo and its working.. when i type which php, its still return /usr/local/bin/php